# C# Windows RT file name too long

Tags: c#, file, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have an app that works from the local storage under appdata to download new content from the web and display it locally. I am finding that content with longer file names is throwing a path too long exception.

This is very bad as I cannot control the level of hierarchy and length of file names in the content. Is there a shortcut or short name (similar to 8.3) that I can use to ensure I am not losing a large percentage of my file path length to? i.e. C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Packages{appid}\LocalState...

In my case I have a shorter name and still the base path takes up 101 characters off the bat

Comment: Could you create a map of short file names and use those instead when a longer file name was requested?

Comment: I cannot find a way to do so using the StorageFolder or StorageFile API's.

Comment: You'd need to store the map. It wouldn't be part of the API.

Answer (score 1):

Paths in windows are generally limited to 260 characters:

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx

> Maximum Path Length Limitation
>
> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following
>   paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is
>   defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following
>   order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by
>   backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the
>   maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string"
>   where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for
>   the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for
>   visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)
>
> Note  File I/O functions in the Windows API convert "/" to "\" as part
>   of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the
>   "\\?\" prefix as detailed in the following sections.
>
> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to
>   permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of
>   32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of components
>   separated by backslashes, each up to the value returned in the
>   lpMaximumComponentLength parameter of the GetVolumeInformation
>   function (this value is commonly 255 characters). To specify an
>   extended-length path, use the "\\?\" prefix. For example, "\\?\D:\very
>   long path".

Not sure that "\\?\" works under RT.  Generally using really long path names under windows isn't a particularly good idea (personally I don't think it's a good idea in general).  Perhaps you can restructure to reduce your path lengths by flattening your structure?

Comment: The unfortunate part is that Microsoft forces you to use local storage when downloading updated content from the web.